# BigQuery Data Transfer Service - Scheduler Not Working

Tags: google-bigquery

I set up a transfer job between Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery yesterday to run at 3:30 AM UTC time. Unfortunately, the job didn't kick off this morning when I checked the logs.

[image: Screenshot of BQ Transfer Job]

The job works when I kick it off manually, but the scheduler doesn't seem to be working. I've tried editing the scheduler time, but nothing works.

Anyone else have this problem? I've been googling this, and it doesn't seem like anyone's had this issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the run time doesn’t get updated to the new run time, until after the job gets kicked off again at its original planned run time, e.g., original job creation time. (This could just be when you edit the job through the BigQuery Data Transfer Service UI. I haven't tried editing the job details programmatically.)

For example:

- On Monday: I create my transfer service job at 5:00 PM. The job kicks off at 5:00 PM. I then edit the job run time to be at 3:00 AM.
- On Tuesday: The job does not run at 3:00 AM. The job runs again at 5:00 PM. During this job, the runtime of the job is updated to 3:00 AM.
- On Wednesday: The job runs at 3:00 AM.